# How to remove timestamp from date without converting to character string

Tags: oracle

I have a query below:

```
Select
ca.CUSTOMID,
ca.SUBMITDATE, 
pe.DATEARRIVED,
CASE WHEN pe.DATEARRIVED IS NOT NULL THEN (ca.SUBMITDATE - pe.DATEARRIVED)/365 ELSE NULL END AS Years_In_Country 
FROM CURUM.CLASS ca
LEFT JOIN CURUM.PERSON pe
ON ca.CUSTOMID = pe.CUSTOMID
```

the problem is, in the database, because ca.SUBMITDATE and pe.DATEARRIVED are displayed as date and timestamp, the years in country column is coming out different. I would like to remove the time stamp from both dates so that the YEARS_IN_COUNTRY displays properly. I also do not want to convert the dates to character but rather keep them in a date format like "2016-01-26"
[image]

If someone can please help me, that would be great.

thank you

Comment: This has nothing to do with how anything is displayed.  What data types are your columns defined as?  My guess is despite the column names saying "date", both columns are defined as `timestamp`.  When you subtract two timestamps, you end up with an interval.  Your calculation appears to expect that both columns are defined as `date` data types so that subtracting them returns a difference in days (and it assumes that leap years are not a thing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't divide by 365 as a year does not always have 365 days. Use the `MONTHS_BETWEEN` function and divide by 12:

```sql
Select ca.CUSTOMID,
       ca.SUBMITDATE, 
       pe.DATEARRIVED,
       MONTHS_BETWEEN( ca.SUBMITDATE, pe.DATEARRIVED )/ 12 AS Years_In_Country 
FROM   CURUM.CLASS ca
       LEFT JOIN CURUM.PERSON pe
       ON ca.CUSTOMID = pe.CUSTOMID
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f121fa8f411da8e601f41cd10a6cfef9)*

> How to remove timestamp from date without converting to character string

This question does not make sense. In Oracle, a `DATE` data type always has year, month, day, hours, minutes and seconds components and a `TIMESTAMP` data type has the same with optional fractional seconds and time zone components. Also, they are both binary data formats (consisting of 7 bytes for a `DATE` and 7 bytes for a `TIMESTAMP(0)` through to 20 bytes for a `TIMESTAMP(9) WITH TIME ZONE`) and, as such, neither have any format associated with them.

If you want to remove the "time" component from a `DATE` or a `TIMESTAMP` then you need to convert them to a different data type that can display formatted date information; that data type would be a string.

So, if you want it to be a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` data type then it will have a "time" component and if you don't want it to be have a "time" component then it will be a string.

If by "remove" you mean that you want to set the "time" component to midnight then just use the `TRUNC` function and the value will be cast to a `DATE` data type where the time components are at midnight. The `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` of the session you are using may be set to not show the time component of a `DATE` data type but it will still exist.

If you want to format the value without a time component then use `TO_CHAR( your_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD' )` to convert it to a formatted string.

Comment: Thank you, the months_between function worked!